# How UART Rx interrupt routine is implemented for variable length data?

Tags: stm32, uart, interrupt-handling, stm32f4, rs485

I have a custom STM32F4 MCU board. I need to receive different types of sequences from Master board in a RS485 n/w. Lengths of data to be received is variable say 10 bytes, 25 bytes and so on. I have to handle every sequence and respond accordingly.

How to properly make use of HAL functions ***HAL_UART_Receive_IT*** and ***HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback*** to receive variable data properly?

I see that 3rd argument of ***HAL_UART_Receive_IT*** is looking for number of bytes to be fixed like shown:

```
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &uart1_rx_byte, no_of_bytes);
```

Please suggest a good implementation...

Receiving frame format:
| Start byte | Slave Addr | Byte count | Func. ID | Data1 | Data2 |...|Data n| Checksum byte 1 | Checksum byte 2 |

Where Byte count = no. of bytes from Func. ID to Checksum byte 2

Comment: Is there an end-of-message indicator that could be used to schedule the message handler? Then the interrupt handler could just put messages in buffers.

Comment: Last two bytes are checksum values and they change as per other data bytes.

Comment: I recommend using UART with DMA and a circular buffer. Then check every ms (or more often) if the data in the buffer contains a complete message. The buffer is handled like a ring buffer. The head pointer is given by the DMA counter, the tail position is managed by your code.

Comment: @codo I'm not sure if I can use Dma properly. For this job I don't want to use dma interface. How do I know if I have a full message in the buffer if the data bytes are not fixed? My header is fixed but tail changes for every sequence.

Comment: From your question I understood that you can determine the message size once you have byte 4. If not, I can't tell you how to detect a full message. After all, you don't really describe the message structure. The advantage of DMA with circular buffer is that you don't need to specify a specific length as you need with *HAL_UART_Receive_IT*.

Comment: @Codo - thanks for the suggestion. but i am not interested in using dma concept as of now. i'm going to shorten my question further to draw people into answering my query..

Comment: If you absolutely do not want to use DMA, then you use *HAL_UART_Receive_IT* twice: first receive 3 bytes and wait for the callback. Then you know the remaining number of bytes in the message. Call it a second time for the remaining number of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your communications speed is slow relative to the MCU clock speeds AND your MCU has nothing better to do, you could do 2-part reception as suggested by @codo in comments (first 3 bytes to get packet length, then receive n bytes from packet header). This will fall apart pretty quickly, if you are looking for higher speeds on a busy system. Another caveat could be bitflips in packet length byte corrupting your message.

Your insistence on sticking to IT and avoiding DMA seems a bit strange, since it literally makes your MCU twitch between the UART peripheral and whatever else it's doing (don't be fooled by the "receive n bytes" - it still generates IRQ on each byte, since peripheral has single data register, just that IRQ processing and memory pointer advancement is hidden by HAL). Receiving with DMA triggers IRQ only once the whole packet has arrived. Setting up DMA with maximum packet size limit and UART_IDLE or timer-based idle detection (if your command source does not provide nicely timed bytes) allows you to process the whole packet once it has arrived.

I'm using UART_IDLE IRQ with DMA at 8Mbaud on 180MHz with FreeRTOS and bunch of other timing-sensitive things happening. At 8Mbaud you only have some 200 cycles per byte to process the message, so IT-driven approach doesn't work that well (context-switching, HAL overhead, etc). I also have packeted structure, similar to yours. Each packet gets verified against length and CRC. Sadly, UART_IDLE IRQ handling is one of the things not implemented in ST HAL, so you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

pleas take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.bepat.de/2020/12/02/stm32f103c8-uart-with-dma-buffer-and-idle-detection/

you have to adapt it a bit for the F4, the correct register for counting the data in the RX-Buffer is

```
huart->hdmarx->Instance->NDTR
```

/wo the "C"

Comment: in short i didn't get you... please be more descriptive.

Comment: you can use the code in the tutorial 1:1, for receiving messages with variable length via UART on the STM32F4. The only thing you have to change in the code is to use the register "NDTR" instead of "CNDTR" in the RxCallback Function